# Focus does not work in Windows Store apps

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I am developing a Windows Store app in C#/XAML. I have couple of TextBoxes and one more button in my page. While clicking the button i start the progress indicator and moving to next page.

In my case, once progress ring started its transition. Focus automatically going to my textbox and it enables Keypad in the bottom even though i did not set any focus to the TextBox. Once progress started in the ring, i tried to set the focus for the Page. But it did not do the trick.

Is there any way to disable this?. It is annoying to the user and blocks the UI in the Tablet. Could you please any one help me on this ?

Comment: can you show us some code? Xaml etc...

Comment: there's a property for the textbox (not only this control, others too), it's called IsTabStop, and refers the availability of focusing the control when pressing the tab key. If you disable the TabStop for that particular textbox, by setting it to IsTabStop="false" it might not get focused.

Comment: I tried IsTabStop but it always disable the focus for the TextBox. But i need a requirement to disable when Progress ring started.

Answer (score 0):

Before starting the `ProgressRing` remove from tab navigation all controls that enables the keypad

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // First remove your TextBox (or all of them) from tab navitaion
    MyTextBox.IsTabStop = false;
    // Now you can start the ProgressRing
    MyProgressRing.IsActive = true;
}
```

If you need you can include again the controls in tab navigation after stop the `ProgressRing`

Comment: I tried this.. But still i am able to reproduce the issue. Any other suggestions. ?

Comment: did you removed all TextBoxs from tab navigation? if so keypad should not appear